# remix ide transact to client.getmiddle pending ... when i run the function getmiddle

Tags: solidity, remix

Beginner at solidity, trying to write a code where a client pays 1 ether to a middle man and that middle man takes 0.5 ether as a cut and sends the rest to the bank. I keep getting this in logs: transact to client.getmiddle pending

```
//filename:practice.sol

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "./Practice2.sol";

contract client{
    middleMan man;
    banks bank;
    constructor(){//client sends one ether to middle man
        bank = new banks();
        man = new middleMan(address(bank));
        address(man).call{value: 1 ether}("");
        }   
   function getmiddle() public returns(uint256){ //middleman pays bank after cutting fees
      uint256 bal = address(man).balance;
        man.payup();
        return bal; //function returns balance with middleman
        
   }
   function getbank() public view returns(uint256){ //functions returns balance with bank
        return address(bank).balance;
   }
   
}

//filename practice2.sol 

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract middleMan{
    address bank;
    constructor(address _bank) {
        bank = _bank;
    }
    receive() external payable{

    }
    function payup() public{
        bank.call{value: 0.5 ether}("");
    }
}

contract banks{
    receive() external payable{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `client` contract it transfers 1 ether to `middleMan` in the constructor

```
constructor() {
    ...
    address(man).call{value: 1 ether}("");
}
```

To do that it needs at least 1 ether in its balance at deployment time.

You can achieve that by transferring 1 ether in the deployment, for that you will need to make the constructor `payable`.